# turn this into a summation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation

I am trying to find two linearly independent power series solutions about $x=0$ for

$$((1-x)^2)y'' -xy' + a^2y =0$$

How do I turn this into a summation from n to infinity?

$$((2n-2)^2 -a^2)((2n-4)^2 -a^2)\dots (2^2 -a^2)(-a^2)$$

Which is all divided by $(2n)!$

Comment: this is not summation, this is product!!

Comment: You are missing things in your question.

Comment: Are you trying to write the left side of your ODE in terms of a series?

Comment: The differential equation is just a bit of background knowledge. I am trying to put the second part of the question in a summation